# FPR in Confusion Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity, false-positive-rate

I was trying to manually calculate $\text{TPR}$ and $\text{FPR}$ for the given data. But unfortunately I dont have any false positive cases in my dataset and even no true positive cases. So I am getting divided by zero error in `pandas`. So I have an intuition that $\text{FPR=1-TPR}$. Please let me know my intuition is correct if not let know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no true/false positives, your classifier has no positive labelings. FPR is simply $\frac{FP}{N}$, where $N$ is number of negatives in the dataset. Assuming there are negative cases in the data, FPR is $0$. TPR is actually $1-\text{FNR}$ (false negative rate), and that is $TP \over P$. Since you have $\text{TP}=0$, and assuming there are positive samples in the dataset, $\text{TPR}$ is also $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The TPR is defined as $\frac{TP}{P}$ (see, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)) or [Encyclopedia of Systems Biology](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9863-7_255) which says it is

> "In machine learning, the true positive rate, also referred to
>   sensitivity or recall, is used to measure the percentage of actual
>   positives which are correctly identified."

or other sources.

So, when there are no positive cases, I would say that the TPR is undefined.

But your question is a little ambiguous, see the other answer, which reads your question differently.